# Rounding up values in the column after aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, rounding

I'm new to pandas, and I know how to format column values into strings to round them up and to convert them into percents. But I'm having problems with doing that on a column that I created as a result of using an `agg()` method:

```
debtors_by_purpose = data.groupby('purpose_id').agg({'debt': ['sum', 'count', 'mean']})
debtors_by_purpose['debt']['mean'] = debtors_by_purpose['debt']['mean'].apply('{:.2%}'.format)
debtors_by_purpose
```

I suspect the reason why it doesn't change is the chained indexing, but I don't know any other way of accessing the elements within a column created by the `agg()` method. I can't use `loc[]` here. And maybe there's a way of putting the `format()` method inside the `agg()` call? Or maybe some alternative method of rounding the values up would be better here?

EDIT: just to be clear, the issue is not that the expression on the right doesn't work. It does work, and I suppose it's my fault for not making a more abstract example. The issue is that the result of this expression **is not saved in the table through the assignment operator**, because I don't know how to avoid chained indexing in this case. I could as well put zero there to illustrate the point that that zero does not get saved.

Comment: Does it work if you change apply to map  `.map('{:.2%}'.format)`

Comment: @MichaelGardner No, it doesn't. If I just leave it as an expression without the assignment, then both versions work. But with the assignment both versions don't affect the original. I'm pretty sure that chained indexing is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN:

```
data = {'purpose_id': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'debt':[50.2,100.80,50.5,200.54,50.02,150.55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
group = df.groupby('purpose_id').agg({'debt': ['sum', 'count', 'mean']})

group['debt', 'mean'] = group['debt', 'mean'].map('{:.2%}'.format))

# OR

group.loc[:, ('debt', 'mean')] = group.loc[:, ('debt', 'mean')].map('{:.2%}'.format)
```

OUT:

```
        debt
    sum count   mean
purpose_id          
1   151.00  2   7550.00%
2   251.04  2   12552.00%
3   200.57  2   10028.50%
```

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand the issue. Your code works, just as mine does, for *display* purposes. But what I'm trying to do is to *change* the values in the table itself, to save the results. That's what I need help with. Also, not quite sure why you're dividing by 1000.

Comment: You haven't provided example data or an expected output so I'm not sure what you want.  

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: All I want is for the thing that you get in your "out" section to be saved within group['debt']['mean'] to be accessed later, rather than printed out just once. I suppose this exact example is not even as important as the answer to a more general question of "how does one avoid chained assignment while working with multilevel columns?". I just want a way to access the "mean" column as a view that *modifies the original*, rather than as a copy.